# Count points inside a pixel in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, point, rasterization

I have a raster and a vector point file.
I need to generate another raster of same resolution showing how many points are inside the corresponding pixels of the original raster.

Something like that:
[image]

Is there a way of doing that in QGIS?

I just want the number of points, no attributes involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to do it in QGIS, but it is quite straightforward with GRASS using the tool [r.in.xyz](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.in.xyz.html) with `method=n`

Have a look at this QA: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Count_points_in_raster_cells